# How to properly setup SS, BP and SP in x86 Real Mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack, bios

I want to know how to properly do it, because the way I'm doing it isn't working.

When setting the `BP` register with 7C00h, then setting the `SP` register with `BP`, then pushing some ASCII, then getting the data from the memory to print it with `INT 10h`, it works just fine.

```
mov ax, 7C00h
mov bp, ax
mov sp, bp

push 'A'

mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, [7BFEh]
int 10h
```

The actual output is

> A

But when I do this:

```
mov ax, 7C00h
mov ss, ax
mov bp, ax
mov sp, bp

...
```

It stops working. The interrupt is called, the cursor moves, but nothing is printed. Also setting `SS` to 0 doesn't work. Please give a hand.

Comment: Set SS to 0. Then you can set SP to 0x7c00 and BP to 0x7c00 as well. Then you have to access the stack value with `mov al, SS:[7BFEh]` as the processor is implicitly doing `mov al, DS:[7BFEh]` so you need to do an SS override.

Comment: You should probably consider setting DS to 0 as well.

Comment: Make sure you set SS then SP *together, in that order* if you set SS at all.  Setting SS only holds off interrupts until the end of the next instruction, and having an interrupt come in with new SS / old SP = possible disaster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at that 7C00h value, you're probably working on a bootloader.
And you want the stack to reside **below** the bootloader.

An important choice that you have to make will be how you want to proceed with the segmented addressing scheme that is in effect at start-up.

### ORG 7C00h

This indicates that the first byte of the code will be at offset 7C00h. For this to work well, you'll have to initialize the segment registers to 0000h. Remember that the bootloader was loaded by BIOS at linear address 00007C00h which is equivalent to segment:offset pair 0000h:7C00h.
If you're going to change the `SP` register, then also change the `SS` segment register. You don't know what it contains at the start of your code and you should (most) always modify these registers in tandem. First assign `SS` and directly after assign `SP`. A `mov` or a `pop` to `SS` blocks many kinds of interruptions between this and the following instruction so that you can safely set a consistent (2-register) stackpointer.

> ```
> mov ss, ax
> mov bp, ax     <== This ignored the above safeguard!
> mov sp, bp
> ```

```
ORG  7C00h

mov  bp, 7C00h
xor  ax, ax
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
mov  ss, ax      ; \  Keep these close together
mov  sp, bp      ; / 

push 'A'         ; This writes 0000h:7BFEh

mov  bx, 0007h   ; DisplayPage and GraphicsColor
mov  al, [7BFEh] ; This requires DS=0
mov  ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
int  10h
```

As an alternative and because you've setup `BP=7C00h`, you could read the stacked character via
`mov al, [bp-2]`.

### ORG 0000h

This indicates that the first byte of the code will be at offset 0000h. For this to work well, you'll have to initialize some of the segment registers to 07C0h. Remember that the bootloader was loaded by BIOS at linear address 00007C00h which is equivalent to segment:offset pair 07C0h:0000h.

Because the stack must go **below** the bootloader, the `SS` segment register will be different from the other segment registers!

```
ORG  0000h

mov  bp, 7C00h
mov  ax, 07C0h
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
xor  ax, ax
mov  ss, ax      ; \  Keep these close together
mov  sp, bp      ; / 

push 'A'         ; This writes 0000h:7BFEh

mov  bx, 0007h   ; DisplayPage and GraphicsColor
mov  al, [bp-2]  ; This uses SS by default
mov  ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
int  10h
```

### ORG 0200h

I've included this one to show that a linear address has many translations to segment:offset.

`ORG 0200h` indicates that the first byte of the code will be at offset 0200h. For this to work well, you'll have to initialize the segment registers to 07A0h. Remember that the bootloader was loaded by BIOS at linear address 00007C00h which is equivalent to segment:offset pair 07A0h:0200h.

Because the 512-bytes stack goes **below** the bootloader, the `SS` segment register will again be equal to the other segment registers!

```
ORG  0200h

mov  bp, 0200h
mov  ax, 07A0h
mov  ds, ax
mov  es, ax
mov  ss, ax      ; \  Keep these close together
mov  sp, bp      ; / 

push 'A'         ; This writes 07A0h:01FEh

mov  bx, 0007h   ; DisplayPage and GraphicsColor
mov  al, [bp-2]  ; This uses SS by default
mov  ah, 0Eh     ; BIOS.Teletype
int  10h
```

You can also fetch the character with `mov al, [01FEh]`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to set `BP` is to not bother. You have no reason to waste one of the 7 precious general purpose registers for "stack frame pointer" to match poorly designed calling conventions from some other language you're not using. Also note that some BIOS functions (e.g. "int 0x10, ah=0x13, write string") use `BP` to pass parameters.

For the same reason, you also have no reason to pass parameters on the stack. For example; for your "print character" code you could pass the character to print in `AL` and delete the `mov al, ...` to make the code smaller (which is extremely important if you're writing "must fit in < 512 bytes" boot code, which is also part of the reason you don't want to waste space setting up and destroying useless stack frame pointers).

For `ss:sp`; they should be treated as a pair (that describes the address of the stack); and you'll want to choose a location for where you want your stack (based on how you're planning to use all the other memory). I'd recommend drawing a little "my physical memory layout" diagram (assuming that you will want to use other areas of memory for various things - an area where more boot code is loaded, an area for a disk IO buffer used when loading a kernel, somewhere to put video mode information, somewhere to put the firmware's memory map, ...).

Note that (at least in my experience) most people diddling with real mode boot code end up wanting to switch between real mode and either protected mode or long mode (whether they realize it initially or not); and in that case it's a lot easier to set all segment registers to zero so that "offset in segment" is (almost) always equal to "physical address" (and if you don't you'll probably end up with bugs caused by accidentally getting segmentation wrong). Note that if SS is zero in real mode (and "SS.base" is zero in protected mode) you can zero extend `SP` (e.g. "`movzx esp,sp`") and continue using the same stack for both real mode and 32-bit protected mode. Also, (after a quick "does the CPU meet my minimum requirements?" check) you can use 32-bit instructions in real mode; and (if `ESP` has been zero extended) you can do things like (e.g.) "`mov al,[esp+10]`" in real mode if/when you need more flexible (32-bit) addressing modes.

Comment: "part of the reason you don't want to waste space setting up and destroying useless stack frame pointers"  Actually in a boot loader setting bp to 7C00h (or wherever the BPB resides) allows accessing variables with bp + imm8 addressing, which is shorter than imm16 addressing.

Comment: @ecm: When the stack contains nothing other than return addresses (because there's no need for local variables and parameters are passed in registers) there's very little reason to care how much instructions you never need cost.

Comment: Right, but for a very common type of loader you do have variables in and above the stack.

Comment: @ecm, I think it really depends on how you develop bootloaders. I usually use `bp` as a scratch register and don't pass parameters via the stack (so I don't need to use memory operands with `bp` as a base]. I usually try to pass what is needed through registers. Usually I end up only pushing registers and popping them to preserve registers across a function call.